# how to get rid of buttons in Atom editor

Tags: atom-editor

Up on top there's a little three lines icon http://fontawesome.io/icon/bars/

I used it to find out how to do things in atom, but it turns out that it's a "button creator" for doing quick actions...

1. How do I get rid of buttons that I don't want?
2. How do I remove this button creator and instead get a "command line" on top of Atom so I can do things, or get help?
3. What is this "button making" feature called?

Or did I misunderstand what I'm using?

Comment: OK it's called: command toolbar. And I found the "toggle command toolbar" which turned it off completely. Now how do I do anything in atom via command line? How do I get the command bar back, and how do I remove buttons from it?

Comment: Are you talking about this package ? https://atom.io/packages/command-toolbar

Comment: Yes, that is the package I'm talking about...

Comment: Ok, then if you want to remove buttons you just have to drag them off the toolbar.

There is no "command line" utility in atom by default, but you can use the "command palette": hit ctrl+p, start typing the command you are looking for and it should autocomplete.

Comment: so put that as an answer and i'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Using the [command-toolbar](https://atom.io/packages/command-toolbar) extension, you can remove buttons by dragging them off the toolbar.
2. There is no "command line" utility in atom by default, but you can use the "command palette": hit ctrl+p, start typing the command you are looking for and it should autocomplete.